# Group data into two columns using jquery to wrap a div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I have 12 items which should be arranged in two columns.  Every 6 items are grouped by `col-sm-6 div`

```
        <div class="row">

         <div class="col-sm-6">
      /*   ......first item  in first column start*/
          <div class="feature-box">
          <div class="feature-box-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
            </div>
              <div class="feature-box-info">
            <h4 class="heading-primary mb-none">Customer Support </h4>
            <p class="tall">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip.</p>
              </div>
    /*...............first item end*/
    .......+5 more
    </div>/* End of col-sm-6 div */


        <div class="col-sm-6">
 /*   ......first item  in second column start*/
         <div class="feature-box">
          <div class="feature-box-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-box-info">
            <h4 class="heading-primary mb-none">Sliders</h4>
          <p class="tall">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p> 
        </div>
     /*...............first item  second column end*/
        .....+ 5 more

        </div>/* End of col-sm-6 div */


    </div>/* End of Row Div*/
```

I am wondering if JQuery could be used to group my data which is being retrieved from a database in 6's by wrapping it with div class col-sm-6?  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: so what you are asking is that all items (divs) with the corresponding class "col-sm-6" should be grouped together in a single table (column doesn't sound right)? Or is it that each "col-sm-6 div should be replaced by a table. I'm not really following on what you are asking ... I'm sure jQuery can be of use, but I need to know what you want before I can help you out.

Comment: Can you show a mockup of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jorex So from my database, I want first 6 items to be wrapped dynamically by  a div  with class "col-sm-6". and the next 6 items to be wrapped by another div with class "col-sm-6"

Comment: @Derek  I have attached a picture of final result - looking at dynamically wrapping first 6 items in a div class " col-sm-6 and the next 6 items in another div class "col-sm-6"